# How to extract a substring from a string in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Suppose I have a string , text2='C:\Users\Sony\Desktop\f.html', and I want to separate "C:\Users\Sony\Desktop" and "f.html" and store them in different variables then what should I do ? I tried out regular expressions but I wasn't successful.

Comment: "\\" is actually a single character, so it is no different from any of the other slashes in your string.

Comment: `os.path.basename(text2)`?

Comment: I have changed the question a little bit . Now I am saving the file in path as 'C:\Users\Sony\Desktop\f.html'

Comment: Rogalski's comment is probably the best approach.

Comment: Yeah os.path.dirname(text2)
Thanks Rogalski :) and Kevin and Celeo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`os.path.split` does what you want:

```
>>> import os
>>> help(os.path.split)
Help on function split in module ntpath:

split(p)
    Split a pathname.

    Return tuple (head, tail) where tail is everything after the final slash.
    Either part may be empty.

>>> os.path.split(r'c:\users\sony\desktop\f.html')
('c:\\users\\sony\\desktop', 'f.html')
>>> path,filename = os.path.split(r'c:\users\sony\desktop\f.html')
>>> path
'c:\\users\\sony\\desktop'
>>> filename
'f.html'
```

Comment: Suppose  p='c:\users\sony\desktop\f.html' , now when I write os.path.split(r p), then it gives me error, how to write this syntax when path is saved in a variable ?

Comment: `r` is only used for literal string constants to suppress requiring escaping backslashes.  It stands for "raw string". Just call `os.path.split(p)`.  I could have typed `os.path.split('c:\\users\\sony\\desktop\\f.html')` instead.